# iPhone: Navigate to another view with transition style and Back button set

Tags: iphone, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I have following code which add BackButton on my view's navigation item's tabbar. It works fine.

```
// Add back button
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[view.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
view.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
view.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
[backButton release];
```

I use following line to navigate to my new view controller but it gets presented with default animation.

```
[view.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

I want to change the way it gets presented so I tried to do it following way.

```
[viewController2 setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [view.navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

This works fine but I lost my BackButton..!! Is there anyway to present my new view controller with specific transition style and also keep my back button as is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to your question. Put a navigation bar on your viewController2 and add a bar button to it using either interface builder or using code. Then in the action of button press

In your viewController2.m write this function and link it up with the button press if you have added the bar button through interface builder.

```
-(void) backButtonPressed : (id) sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This should solve your problem. 
Doing a pushViewController will carry forward the navigationBar and all for you but in your case presenting a viewController as modalViewController will not give you the navigationBar by default so you have to add it manually in your modalViewController which is viewController2 in your case.

Please let me know if you are still facing problems. We can fix it soon and save you some time and frustration.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for you effort. I am already doing at some places what you suggested but in this case ViewController2 is dynamic variable.

UIViewController *viewController2 = [appDelegate getViewControllerForViewID:viewID];

The view Id is based on what user clicks and the way I architectured my App. I am not sure if I would be able to implement your suggestion here.

Comment: what do you mean by a dynamic variable?

Comment: You can implement my suggestion for sure. If you are sure that the backbutton and the bar has to be shown in case of every viewController. Why not add a bar on top of everyViewController that is returned by [appDelegate getViewControllerForViewID:viewID]. If I am misinterpreting something please elaborate some more. I am sure I can try to find a solution for you.

Comment: I can't add bar on every viewcontroller. If the action is to open ViewModal then back button won't be get displayed. Anyway it seems there is only one way to do. I will need to tweak something in my design.